# Lucene.NET 2.9 and BitArray/DocIdSet

Tags: lucene.net, faceted-search

I found a great example on grabbing facet counts on a base query. It stores the bitarray of the base query to improve the performance each time the a facet gets counted.

```
        var genreQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("genre", genre));
        var genreQueryFilter = new QueryFilter(genreQuery);
        BitArray genreBitArray = genreQueryFilter.Bits(searcher.GetIndexReader());
        Console.WriteLine("There are " + GetCardinality(genreBitArray) + " document with the genre " + genre);

        // Next perform a regular search and get its BitArray result
        Query searchQuery = MultiFieldQueryParser.Parse(term, new[] {"title", "description"}, new[] {BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD}, new StandardAnalyzer());
        var searchQueryFilter = new QueryFilter(searchQuery);
        BitArray searchBitArray = searchQueryFilter.Bits(searcher.GetIndexReader());
        Console.WriteLine("There are " + GetCardinality(searchBitArray) + " document containing the term " + term);
```

The only problem is that I am using a newer version of Lucene.NET (2.9) and Filter.Bits is obsolete. We are told to use DocIdSet instead (rather than BitArray).

I cannot found out how to do the bitArray.And(bitArray) with a docIdSet. I looked in reflector and found OpenIdSet which has And operations. Not sure if OpenIdSet is the route to go, I'm just stating.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found it out.

```
            var productsDISI = new OpenBitSetDISI(productResults.Iterator(), 25000);
            var termQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Spec" + expectedFacet.SpecificationId, expectedFacet.SpecificationOptionId.ToString()));
            var termQueryFilter = new QueryWrapperFilter(termQuery);
            var termIterator = termQueryFilter.GetDocIdSet(productReader).Iterator();
            productsDISI.InPlaceAnd(termIterator);
            var total = productsDISI.Cardinality();
```

turns out to be much faster too.

Comment: thanks for sharing the answer, saved me many hours of research